# Gradle build failed after adding ads

Tags: unity, android, unity-ads, gradle

There is problem with Android building. After adding ads, when I click on build, it shows the following error:

> Issue with Android dependencies detected: The SDK has resolved to an incompatible version with the Package. This may result in unexpected behaviour. To avoid this, include the mainTemplate.gradle file by checking the checkbox (Custom Main Gradle Template) in Edit > Project Settings > Player > Publishing
> Settings. Would you like to cancel the build?`

And when I check 'Custom Main Gradle Template' and click build it shows the following error:

> `Gradle build failed. See Console for details.`

These are the details shown in the Console:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 5 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <63965ae56af7489797f355b7c1211ab2>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <63965ae56af7489797f355b7c1211ab2>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
[Mediation]: Only copying gradle lock files, no lockfile generation
UnityEngine.Logger:Log (string,object)
Unity.Services.Mediation.MediationLogger:Log (object) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.services.mediation@1.0.5/Runtime/Tools/Logger/MediationLogger.cs:21)
Unity.Mediation.Build.Editor.AndroidLockFilePostGenerateGradleProject:CopyExistingLockFiles (string,string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.services.mediation@1.0.5/Editor/Build/PostGradle/AndroidLockFilePostGenerateGradleProject.cs:140)
Unity.Mediation.Build.Editor.AndroidLockFilePostGenerateGradleProject:OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject (string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.services.mediation@1.0.5/Editor/Build/PostGradle/AndroidLockFilePostGenerateGradleProject.cs:82)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:lintVitalRelease'.
> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
  The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1, androidx.core:core:1.6.0, androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0, androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0, androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.1, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.1.0, androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0, androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.1.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0, androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.1.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.5.1, androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1, androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0, androidx.room:room-common:2.2.5, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0, androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0, androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.5.1, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0, androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0, androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0, androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0, androidx.print:print:1.0.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
USERDOMAIN = SERVERNBEAST
asl.log = Destination=file
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
TMP = C:\Users\chmuh\AppData\Local\Temp
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 9705
OneDriveConsumer = C:\Users\chmuh\OneDrive
OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_6700_CVKHSUXRYWUAGZTV
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 151 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\chmuh
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
USERNAME = chmuh
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 12
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
TEMP = C:\Users\chmuh\AppData\Local\Temp
Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\chmuh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\chmuh\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin
COMPUTERNAME = SERVERNBEAST
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemDrive = C:
windir = C:\WINDOWS
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
HOMEPATH = \Users\chmuh
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\Users\chmuh\AppData\Roaming
OneDrive = C:\Users\chmuh\OneDrive
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS
SESSIONNAME = Console
LOGONSERVER = \\SERVERNBEAST
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\chmuh\AppData\Local
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH = C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
HOMEDRIVE = C:
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = SERVERNBEAST
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:lintVitalRelease'.
> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
  The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1, androidx.core:core:1.6.0, androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0, androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0, androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.1, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.1.0, androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0, androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.1.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0, androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.1.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.5.1, androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1, androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0, androidx.room:room-common:2.2.5, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0, androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0, androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.5.1, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0, androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0, androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0, androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0, androidx.print:print:1.0.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <bf5a7d3f06424428a0a228b33a117c52>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <63965ae56af7489797f355b7c1211ab2>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 408 seconds (407644 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 5 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <63965ae56af7489797f355b7c1211ab2>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <63965ae56af7489797f355b7c1211ab2>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Before adding the Ads plugin, the Andriod building was working fine.